# Python Tkinter Rendering Bug in Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, checkbox, tkinter, rendering

I am using Windows 10 and trying to create Tkinter app,

but I have problem with Checkbuttons and Radiobuttons size when hovering.

this is checkbox when program is started

[image]

this is same checkbox but after hovering
and you can see that its became little bit small then before

[image: this is rendered checkbox]

where is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The following works as desired with no size change on my Win10 machine with PSF's 3.5.1 (tk 8.6.4) installer.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root=tk.Tk()
ttk.Checkbutton(root).pack()
```

If this does not work for you, how is your install different?  If it does, add code to match yours a *bit at a time* until the problem occurs.